# NDK can't compile c++0x

Tags: gcc, c++11, compiler-errors, android-ndk

has anybody met this, that I've added "LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++0x" to file "Application.mk",and I'm sure the mk-file obviously works.But eventually,it lie down at an "auto",anybody know why?
Version:NDKr7,gcc 4.4.3.

Comment: Application.mk contains settings common to the whole project. Android.mk contains one or more module definitions. Variables starting with `LOCAL_` are local to a single module, put it in the same place as `LOCAL_MODULE` and friends.

Comment: Not exactly related to your current issue, and you might already be aware of this, but 4.4 is quite old, and the majority of C++0x features [were added in later versions](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). So if you want to take advantage of things like range-based for-loops and lambda-expressions you'll need to use a newer version of gcc.

Comment: can you show us the code line where the first error appears? IIRC, gcc 4.4 already supported `auto`, but not e.g. range-for loops so something like `for (auto i : myvector)` will not compile (which was added in gcc 4.6). See http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html for a list of C++0x features in gcc 4.4.